# Best way to hide/unhide hundreds of DOM elements: change STYLE or CLASS?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

### two ways

There are two common ways to dynamically change the visibility of an element with javascript...

By modifying its `style`:

```js
// occupies same space when hidden
elem.style.visibility = 'hidden' // 'visible' to unhide

// does not occupy any space when hidden
elem.style.display = 'none' // 'block' | 'inline' to unhide
```

By modyfying its `classList`:

```js
elem.classList.add('hidden') // classList.remove('hidden') to unhide
```

```css
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden; /* occupies same space when hidden */
    /* display: none;   /* does not occupy any space when hidden */
}
```

> ℹ️ There are other properties that can be used such as `opacity` (See @Kingfish's comment), but they all must still be updated by either modifying their `style` or their `classList`.

### but which is better for hiding/unhiding *large numbers* of elements?

For one or a few elements, modifying `style` or `classList` will work the same. But I need to change the visibility of dozens or even hundreds of elements. For volume changes, Which methods is better in terms of the following?

- minimizing CPU usage
- minimizing redraw latency
- minimizing UI thread blocking

I have a very fast computer so it is hard to know the impacts on people with more performance constrained devices.

### is there a third way?

All of the elements I want to show/hide in unison have a specific class. It seems most logical that I should be able to modify the CSS rules for that class, i.e. to set its CSS visibility property, rather than add/remove another class for each of the hundreds of members of the class. I've researched this and few people talk about it, which makes me wonder if it is considered a hack, not-compatible across browsers, or bad for some other reason.

Is there a well-founded explanation one way or the other?

Comment: This may be helpful": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

Comment: According to https://www.sitepoint.com/hide-elements-in-css/, opacity: 0 offers the best performance because it utilizes hardware acceleration and doesn't redraw the layout. Of course it leaves you with empty space on your display, but as you were considering visibility as an option, that might not be a concern. The hidden elements are still susceptible to events

Comment: In General, changing classes is preferred over direct changes to properties only because it scales better and is easier to manage, not necessarily because of performance. But, when making changes to properties, you need to be careful to organize them into batches so they can be processed as a single action and only cause a single paint/reflow. So, with that in mind, applying a class is better than changing CSS properties separately.

Comment: @Kinglish thanks that's useful info! But it still doesn't answer my fundamental question. See the ℹ️ note I added above.

Comment: @ScottMarcus That page specifically says "Don't apply will-change to too many elements". RE second comment: If I'm hiding 300 elements, it's still 300 JS operations whether I am setting a style property or adding a class. The JS has exactly the same complexity. Are you saying the JS engine can do one faster than the other, or that the DOM rendering for one is faster? Do you have a source. Or are you suggesting "the third way" I mention above? Do you have a source? If you do, please write an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a third way?

Yes, there is. There's even a fourth way.

> All of the elements I want to show/hide in unison have a specific class. It seems most logical that I should be able to modify the CSS rules for that class, i.e. to set its CSS visibility property, rather than add/remove another class for all of these elements.

Yes, this is possible, using the [CSS Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model). Get the stylesheet defining the rule, get the rule for that class, and change its definition.

It's not a hack, and has good browser support. It's rarely done because few people know about it, and because accessing the right rule is a bit fiddly (which you can work around by creating and inserting the rule object using CSSOM in the first place). I'm not certain how well-optimised it is - but it certainly needs less JS processing than to alter each individual element.

However, there's a much easier solution: use *cascading* style sheets!

```
body.hide-x .x {
    display: none; 
}
/* or, reverse:
.x {
    display: none;
}
body.show-x .x {
    display: inline;
}
*/
```

```
document.body.classList.toggle('hide-x');
```

This will show/hide all elements with class `x` inside the document, based on whether the `show-x` class is applied to the body or not.

You can replace `display: none` with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` or any other property change you want to apply en masse depending on your needs.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?! I already use the `<html class="no-js">` trick which essentially works the same way.

Comment: Thanks for such a well written answer!